# VBA Date format method giving different centuries

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using the below function I am getting different centuries .Kindly let me know why this is happening and how I can control the century.

Format("1/12/30", "dd MMMM yyyy")
Result -01 December 1930

Format("1/12/20", "dd MMMM yyyy")
Result - 01 December 2020

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/two-digit-year-numbers

Comment: You have to add the century.... (though did you do this in Word or Excel, because for me Word returns 2030 and not 1930).

Comment: It was MS word. Thanks @BigBen .Understood the reason .As you have provided the solution in comment I wnt be able to vote for it.

Comment: I wondered... maybe a regional or version-defined setting. Sorry, just recently stumbled across the Excel documentation. I couldn't find a Word equivalent, but didn't look too long.

Comment: Regional setting worked for me and the issue is resolved. Thanks again @BigBen .My  apologies for not giving  you the credit .

Comment: No credit needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your Region settings : [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/two-digit-year-numbers)